# Lazy Evaluation on condition variables

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

In the following code snippet, would compiler do lazy evaluation on condition variables and also do short circuit evaluation?

```
const bool condition1 = calcCondition1(...);
const bool condition2 = calcCondition2(...);
const bool condition3 = calcCondition3(...);

if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3)
  return true;
return false
```

Such that the actual flow would be something like the following?

```
if(!calcCondition1(...))
  return false;
if(!calcCondition2(...))
  return false;
if(!calcCondition3(...))
  return false;
return true;
```

Thank you!

Comment: If the left operand of the logical AND operator evaluates to false then the right operand is not evaluated. As for the function calls then they will be called when the constants are defined.

Comment: If you want lazy execution either call the functions inside the `if` or do the second form to make it explicit. What you're describing there is referred to as "guard clauses" and are pretty typical anyway, so it's a patter that should not be too surprising.

Comment: There us no lazy evaluation in C, except as permitted by the as-if rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if compiler is sure that such a optimization does not change any visible semantic of the program (see `__attribute__((pure))` example below).

No in other cases. Note that function bodies from different compilation units (different `.cpp` file) are unknown: they are linked into binary after compilation process.

The compiler must assume worst-case scenarios such as `calcCondition1` throws an exception or executes `exit()`. Or mutate some global state. And in such cases, the semantics must be preserved and everything must be invoked in the written order

That code

```cpp
bool calcCondition1();
bool calcCondition2();
bool calcCondition3();

bool foo() {
    const bool condition1 = calcCondition1();
    const bool condition2 = calcCondition2();
    const bool condition3 = calcCondition3();

    if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) return true;
    return false;
}
```

and example assembly output:

```
foo():                                # @foo()
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        call    calcCondition1()@PLT
        mov     ebp, eax
        call    calcCondition2()@PLT
        mov     ebx, eax
        call    calcCondition3()@PLT
        and     bl, bpl
        and     al, bl
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Notice that all functions are called one by one

If compiler is sure that it is not a case (I am using a [gcc extension)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html):

```cpp
__attribute__((pure)) bool calcCondition1();
__attribute__((pure)) bool calcCondition2();
__attribute__((pure)) bool calcCondition3();

bool foo() {
    const bool condition1 = calcCondition1();
    const bool condition2 = calcCondition2();
    const bool condition3 = calcCondition3();

    if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then the generated code use the short circuit evaluation

```
foo():                                # @foo()
        push    rbx
        call    calcCondition1()@PLT
        test    al, al
        je      .LBB0_4
        call    calcCondition3()@PLT
        mov     ebx, eax
        call    calcCondition2()@PLT
        test    bl, bl
        je      .LBB0_4
        mov     ecx, eax
        mov     al, 1
        test    cl, cl
        je      .LBB0_4
        pop     rbx
        ret
.LBB0_4:
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

, because compiler is sure that functions are pure, so there is a more rooms for optimizations.

Comment: It depends, if compiler sees body of functions (and these functions are pure) then why not? Compiler is allowed to do any optimization, if program behaves in the same way. My second example shows that the `pure` annotation allows to do short circuiting when optimizations are enabled (even though bodies are unkown)

Comment: @Dúthomhas: The case where optimization is legal is when the functions can inline, and the compiler can see that it's just optimizing away some reads and computation to produce the boolean.  Not side effects or writes, as you say that would violate the "as if" rule.  (Or when you use `__attribute__((pure))` or `__attribute__((const))` to promise that it's a pure function, no such side effects, as in this answer.)

Comment: @Dúthomhas i have changed the answer